# Android access android/media folder with API 30 / Android R (11)

Tags: android, file, storage

is it possible to access files from android/media directory? I can only list dirs with listFiles in app folders but not files.

is there a function for that?

thank you!

Comment: What is android/media?

Comment: The file path /sdcard/Android/media/

Comment: The function is the same. Only Android 11 considers the owner of files hence you will not see files from other apps. And default your app cannot create files there so there is little to see while listing. Use saf instead.

Comment: I dont want to create files only read them. I thought that would be possible... I hate the new storage system...